# X509 Configuration for webservice on WAS8 server

Tags: web-services, ws-security

Currently I am configuring X.509 WS-Security on WAS8 for my web service.

As far as I know, the client calling my web service needs to sign the content using X.509 (e.g. using Spring-WS), and `WAS` server will validate the signed content based on the X.509 configuration on `WAS` server.

Also as far as I know **the web service does not require any change to support X.509**, as authentication and validation is between the web serivce client and the WAS8 server, as by the time the request comes to the web service it would be getting the expected XML payload in plain text.

Can someone confirm/validate if my understanding of  **web service is not required any change to support X.509** is correct?

Comment: @G. Samaras: please use `code formatting` only for code, not for normal words like "webservice".

Comment: @S.L.Barth roger that.